# Pandas - Extract a string starting with a particular character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find, slice

It should be fairly simple yet I'm not able to achieve it.

I have a dataframe df1, having a column "name_str". Example below:

```
   name_str 
0    alp:ha
1    bra:vo
2  charl:ie
```

I have to create another column that would comprise - **say 5 characters** - that start **after** the colon (:). I've written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name_str':["alp:ha", "bra:vo", "charl:ie"]}
#indx = ["name_1",]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
n= df1['name_str'].str.find(":")+1
df1['slize'] = df1['name_str'].str.slice(n,2)
print(df1)
```

But the output is disappointing: NaanN

```
   name_str  slize
0    alp:ha    NaN
1    bra:vo    NaN
2  charl:ie    NaN
```

The output should've been:

```
   name_str  slize
0    alp:ha    ha
1    bra:vo    vo
2  charl:ie    ie
```

Would anyone please help? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract everything after the colon with this regular expression: `:(.*)`

```
df1['slize'] = df1.name_str.str.extract(':(.*)')                                                  

>>> df1                                                                                                
   name_str slize
0    alp:ha    ha
1    bra:vo    vo
2  charl:ie    ie
```

**Edit, based on your updated question**

If you'd like to extract up to 5 characters after the colon, then you can use this modification:

```
df['slize'] = df1.name_str.str.extract(':(.{,5})')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's been helpful. However I'm looking to get a fixed number of characters after colon (:). I've edited the original question as well. Please check if you can share a solution?

Comment: This one seems to be working: df1['slize'] = df1['name_str'].str.extract(':(.....)

Comment: See my updated answer for getting up to a set number of characters after the `:`.

Comment: Works well. Though I get a warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Hello, I tried to use ':(.*)' to extract everything after the colon but my "everything after" is a string that have \n on it, like ":AAA\neee\n" and ':(.*)'  stops on the first \n. Any idea of solutions? Thanks!