# Extract text strings after certain word and create a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy

I have a `df`:

```
     ClassOfYear
0    ClassOfYear 2019 something
1    x ClassOfYear 2012 random text 
2    Amy ClassOfYear 2004
3    David Beckham ClassOfYear 1994
     ...
```

I'd like to create a new column with only texts after and including `ClassOfYear`. i.e.:

```
     ClassOfYear
0    ClassOfYear 2019 something
1    ClassOfYear 2012 random text 
2    ClassOfYear 2004
3    ClassOfYear 1994
     ...
```

---

Edit:
Usually there is a year in each string, can we create another column with the year?
Expected Output:

```
     ClassOfYear                    Year
0    ClassOfYear 2019 something     2019
1    ClassOfYear 2012 random text   2012
2    ClassOfYear 2004               2004
3    ClassOfYear 1994               1994
     ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Extract a string starting with a particular character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913682/pandas-extract-a-string-starting-with-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `str.replace`:

```
df["NewCol"]= df["ClassOfYear"].str.replace("^.*(?=ClassOfYear)", "")
```

This approach is to match all content from the start of the column up to, but not including, the text `ClassOfYear`.  Then, we replace with empty string to remove this text.  Note that this replacement would not affect column values which do not have the text `ClassOfYear` at all.

Comment: Hi @tim-biegeleisen, that's a nice trick. However, I'm trying the same script for this sentence: `no reportable sports were identified, including soccer, cricket, and basketball.`  where I want extract all the words after `including`

Comment: @Roy Assuming you want to capture these names as a _string_, then use the pattern `\bincluding (.*)$`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regular expression with `assign` or just broadcast your column.

`.*` is a greedy approach to match everything after `ClassOfYear` until the end of a string (except for line terminators)

```
df = df.assign(newCol=df['ClassOfYear'].str.extract('(ClassOfYear.*)'))

print(df)

                          ClassOfYear                         newCol
0          ClassOfYear 2019 something     ClassOfYear 2019 something
1     x ClassOfYear 2012 random text   ClassOfYear 2012 random text 
2                Amy ClassOfYear 2004               ClassOfYear 2004
3      David Beckham ClassOfYear 1994               ClassOfYear 1994
```